# Unable to delete data from database although the user is authenticated?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, rules

I am really stuck with this problem.I'm trying to delete some user from realtimedatabase firebase. I'm using email/password authentication provide from Firebase. After I re-authentificate the user I try to delete data from db. I receive permission denied error from firebase(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied). Why?

Here is my code:

```
    public void reAuthenticateUser(String password) {
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
            .getCredential(user.getEmail(), password);
    user.reauthenticate(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        handleExceptions(task.getException());
                    } else {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        DBHelper.getInstance().deleteUser(user.getUid());//the problem is here

                        deleteUserAccount();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Here is my DBHelper class:

```
 public class DBHelper {

private static DBHelper instance = null;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference ref;

private DBHelper() {
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
}

public static DBHelper getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new DBHelper();

    return instance;
}

public void saveUserOnDB(String userId, String name, String email) {
    ref = database.getReference().child("users");
    ref.child(userId).setValue(new User(name, email));
}

public void deleteUser(String userId) {
    ref = database.getReference().child("users");
    ref.child(userId).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.e("TAG","onComplete",task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Firebase rules:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

In debug mode, all works fine and, also, when I switch the database rules to public, the data is deleted from db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are deleting the user's account after you request deletion of the user's data:

```
DBHelper.getInstance().deleteUser(user.getUid());

deleteUserAccount(); // <== does this call FirebaseUser.delete()?
```

If so, you are probably creating a race condition where the account deletion is taking effect before the asynchronous data deletion has completed.  Move the call to `deleteUserAccount()` into the completion listener for the data deletion:

```
public void deleteUser(String userId) {
    ref = database.getReference().child("users");
    ref.child(userId).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                deleteUserAccount();  // <== MOVE HERE
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG","onComplete",task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```